# TinyDB error putint null object reference android

Tags: java, android, object, reference, tinydb

[TinyDb class is here](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)

im using it simply by default codes like : `TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(MyActivity.this);` and `tinyDB.putInt("hadi" , 10);`

but im getting an error that i cant understand . it say tinyDB is  null object reference . you can see the error below :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.ahmadi.TinyDB.TinyDB.putInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create Object of Your TinyDB class like :-

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB();
```

Comment: not working . error :                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: error line in tinydb class : line 51 .line 51 code : "preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);
"

Comment: now you are getting N.P.E. on SharedPreference  ..Post Shared Preference code

Comment: TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(Myactivity.this);

Comment: i just use this code . "        tinyDB.putInt("hadi" , 10);
"

Comment: If you have only that much of code than why this line generating error! preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);

Comment: im using tinyDB class . that error is in that class

Comment: this is the hole class http address  : https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Answer (score 0):

You should properly initiate your **TinyDB** before using it!

For Example in `Activity`:

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(this); 
tinyDB.putInt("hadi" , 10);
```

or in `Fragment`:

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(getContext()); 
tinyDB.putInt("hadi" , 10);
```

**TinyDB** is just a simple wrapper around `SharedPreferences` so it is important that you provide a valid `Context` to it to initiate `SharedPreferences`

Comment: you are welcome! just remember to pass the right context to tiny db! else your app can crash when activity or fragment is destroyed..

Comment: roger that . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you are passing context before Oncreate just pass the context after oncreate donot make it global variable.